# Creating a list from a .txt using the for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to complete a worksheet, but got stuck again. I need to store all the comments of Mooneye Studios in a list that is updated each time there is a new comment from the creator of the project. I am trying to do so with the first two conditions in the for loop. I get moon = [\n, \n, \n....]. Any idea how to proceed and make this work?
The file looks like this [http://imgur.com/bsSr06q](https://imgur.com/bsSr06q).

```
comments = open('lostEmberComments.txt', 'r')
nbOfCom = 0 #counting the commentaries
people = []# list of ppl who have commented
creator = False # did the creator write the comment?
moon = [] # lists of comments made by the creator
temp= ''

for line in comments:
   # my attempt
   if '>>> Mooneye Studios' in line:
     creator = True
   if creator and '>>>' not in line:
     temp += line


   if '>>>' and 'Mooneye Studios' not in line:
     creator = False
       if temp != '':
         moon.append(temp)
         temp = ''

   # this section is for the first part of the excercise
   if '>>>' in line:
      nbOfCom += 1 # counting the commentaries
      if not line.rstrip('\n') in people:  # avoiding duplicates
        people.append(line.rstrip('\n'))


b = len(people)

print(moon)
print('Discussion participants: ', people)
print('There are ', b, 'contributors to the discussion.')
print('There are ',nbOfCom,' commentaries on this project.')

comments.close()
```

Comment: \n is a newline in Linux, u can use line.replace("\n", "")

Comment: It is supposed to be if creator IS in line and >>> not in line.

Comment: I do not believe the following condition: `if '>>>' and 'Mooneye Studios' not in line:` is doing what you might think it is doing. I believe you mean `if '>>>' not in line and 'Mooneye Studios' not in line`

Comment: Yes, sorry, copy-pasted the wrong line.

Comment: Or, it could be `if '>>>' in line and 'Mooneye Studios' not in line`

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has helped..

Comment: Why did you put a **link to an image** instead of simply copying-pasting the text file??? Please copy the text here it would be much simpler for others to test the code!

Comment: Yes, well, that is only *one* bug in your code. This isn't really a homework service, but since you at least showed effort I'm trying to give you some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not on the *first two* if statements but on the *third* if statement because the first part (`'>>>'`) of the third if statement is always true.  It will then save only the first empty line of creator's comment by the *second* if statement.  The change mentioned by @juanpa, `if '>>>' in line and 'Mooneye Studios' not in line`, may solve the problem.

There is also another issue of your code that if the last comment in the file is from creator, it will not be saved to `moon[]`.

Below is my suggested solution:

```
nbOfCom = 0
people = []
creator = False
moon = []
temp = ''

with open('lostEmberComments.txt') as comments:
    for line in comments:
        if line.startswith('>>> '): # start of new comment
            nbOfCom += 1
            if temp and creator: # previous comment is from creator
                moon.append(temp)
                temp = ''
            commenter = line.rstrip()[4:] # get the commenter's name
            creator = 'Mooneye Studios' == commenter
            if commenter not in people:
                people.append(commenter)
        elif creator:
            temp += line # save creator's comment

# don't miss the last comment in file if it is from creator
if temp and creator:
    moon.append(temp)

print(moon)
print('Discussion participants:', people)
print('There are', len(people), 'contributors to the discussion.')
print('There are', nbOfCom, 'commentaries on this project.')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `if` is not the same as `elif` for conditions following the first one.
In the second case, you would pass by only one branch, in the first case, you pass by all the branches where the condition is true.

Next, especially if you are a beginner, you should always describe on a paper sheet what you are trying to achieve, said differently clearly describe the algorythm, the tests and branches. And think twice whether the algorythm processes correctly corner cases, and weather reordering tests could avoid to test multiple time the same condition: it will save execution time and will ease future modification of the code because there will be less repetitions. And only then convert it in Python code.

Finally, when you do not get expected results and do not understand why, just add traces in your code to easily follow what lines were really executed, or alternatively use the debug mode of Python.

Your current code could become (more or less):

```
with open('lostEmberComments.txt', 'r') as comments:
    nbOfCom = 0
    people = []
    moon = []
    tmp = ''
    for line in comments:
        if line.startswith('>>>'):  # start of a new comment
            nbOfCom += 1            # count it
            if (len(tmp.strip()) != 0) and creator: # was previous a creator's one
                moon.append(tmp)    # store it
            tmp = ''
            if 'Mooneye Studios' in line:  # process current comment
                creator = True
            else:
                creator = False
                line = line.rstrip()       # not a creator's one
                if not line in people:     # add the name if is does not already exists
                    people.append(line)
        elif creator:
            tmp += line             # a continuing line of a creator's comment

# print the results
...
```